# How to check if at least one input is completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGJZmP)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<form class="add-patient">
  <fieldset style="display: block;">
          <label for="new_exam">New exam</label>
          <input type="text" name="new_exam" id="new_exam" value="">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset style="display: block;">
          <label for="x_ray">X ray</label>
          <input type="text" name="x_ray" id="x_ray"  value="">
  </fieldset>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-submit" onclick="sendForm();" value="Create report">
</form>
```

**CODE JS:**

```
 function sendForm() {
        var status_form = false;
        $(".add-patient input").each(function(){
           if($(this).val() == ""){
             status_form = true;
           }
        });
        console.log(status_form);
        var createdBy = jQuery('#created_by').val();

        if( status_form )
        {
            alert('Fill at least one field');
        }else{
            alert("now it's ok");
        }
 }
```

I want to do a check ... if an input is complete when displaying the message "it; s ok" ... otherwise displaying another message
probably means the code clearly what they want to do.

You can help me with a solution please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Increase the count if `value == ''` and if `count == number of inputs` then ....

Comment: try by checking when user focus out from any input field may help

Comment: can you show me a short example please?thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.filter` to get the length of the input elements having value as `''`

Try this:

```js
function sendForm() {
  var elem = $(".add-patient input[type='text']");
  var count = elem.filter(function() {
    return !$(this).val();
  }).length;
  if (count == elem.length) {
    alert('Fill at least one field');
  } else {
    alert("now it's ok");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="add-patient">
  <fieldset style="display: block;">
    <label for="new_exam">New exam</label>
    <input type="text" name="new_exam" id="new_exam" value="">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset style="display: block;">
    <label for="x_ray">X ray</label>
    <input type="text" name="x_ray" id="x_ray" value="">
  </fieldset>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-submit" onclick="sendForm();" value="Create report">
</form>
```